# how to place an icon badge on ionic?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, badge, ionicons

how to design a card with notification badge without number with ionic and scss

[image]

make it as follows Badge without number

[image]

I have the following scss but it is not responsive

```
<ion-card class="ion-margin-top">
     <ion-badge color="danger">1</ion-badge>
     <ion-icon name="settings-outline"></ion-icon>
     <ion-card-content>
       <span class="contentText">Configuration</span>
     </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>

ion-card {
   background: #fff;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   margin: 0;
 
   ion-icon {
     width: 75%;
     margin-top: 16px;
     font-size: 5em;
   }
   ion-badge {
       position: absolute;
       top: 20px;
       right: 50px;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To ion-badge css, add

```
z-index:100;
```

this will bring the badge in front of the icon..

add `--color` attribute which will change the color of the text, make it same as that of your background..

`--background` can be used for specifying the background color of the badge.

[Reference Docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/badge#css-custom-properties)

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation, but I want to take your number off and leave it as a notification without number.

Comment: Badge without number

Comment: then i would suggest you add a static image over the icon.. because even if you remove the number, the badge might not turn out to be a perfect circle... refer this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text.asp

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this myself, then I saw someone used it like that, just simply add to `<IonIcon mode='ios' />`

[image: see screenshot for result]